# How do I give a role to someone in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots, roles

I've been trying to code a single reaction role all night but I can't get the code to work, the bot reacts to the message and everything but it doesn't give me the role when I react

Here's my code

```
@bot.command(name='rolecreate', help='creates all the default roles')
async def rolecreate(ctx):
  Text= "React with :heart: to get the He/Him role!"
  Moji1 = await ctx.send(Text)
  reaction='❤️'
  await Moji1.add_reaction(reaction)
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member, ctx):
    Channel = bot.get_channel('881380132789583892')
    if reaction.message.channel.name!= Channel:
          return
          if reaction.emoji == "❤️":
            guild= ctx.guild
              he_him = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="He/Him")

          if not he_him:
            he_him = await guild.create_role(name="He/Him")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take the code after `if reaction.emoji == "❤️":` out of the parent `if` statement. It seems like the first `if` statement is behavior that we don't want and the rest of the code belongs to a different logic path. Any code after a `return` doesn't get executed.

Can you try this?

```py
@bot.command(name='rolecreate', help='creates all the default roles')
async def rolecreate(ctx):
  Text= "React with :heart: to get the He/Him role!"
  Moji1 = await ctx.send(Text)
  reaction='❤️'
  await Moji1.add_reaction(reaction)
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member, ctx):
    Channel = bot.get_channel('881380132789583892')
    if reaction.message.channel.name!= Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "❤️":
        guild= ctx.guild
        he_him = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="He/Him")

        if not he_him:
            he_him = await guild.create_role(name="He/Him")
```

Comment: No, that didn't work, the bot still send out the message but when I clicked on the reaction it didn't give me the role